# Automapper configure 2 classes to one

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-6

I have the following DB (Infrastructure) classes:

```
[Table("ApplicationDriverEquipments")]
public partial class ApplicationDriverEquipment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Make { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Year { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string VINNumber { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string PlateNumber { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string CurrentMileage { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Length { get; set; }


    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationDriverEquipmentType Type { get; set; }

    public int DriverId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationDriver Driver { get; set; }
}

[Table("ApplicationDriverEquipmentTypes")]
public partial class ApplicationDriverEquipmentType
{
    public ApplicationDriverEquipmentType()
    {
        Equipments = new HashSet<ApplicationDriverEquipment>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationDriverEquipment> Equipments { get; set; }
}
```

and the following DTO (Domain) classes:

```
public abstract class ApplicationDriverEquipmentAbstractDomain
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string PlateNumber { get; set; }
    public string CurrentMileage { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; protected set; }
}

public class ApplicationDriverEquipmentTractorDomain : ApplicationDriverEquipmentAbstractDomain
{
    public ApplicationDriverEquipmentTractorDomain()
    {
        Type = ApplicationDriverEquipmentTypeStaticStringsDomain.Tractor;
    }
    public string VINNumber { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDriverEquipmentTrailerDomain : ApplicationDriverEquipmentAbstractDomain
{
    public ApplicationDriverEquipmentTrailerDomain()
    {
        Type = ApplicationDriverEquipmentTypeStaticStringsDomain.Trailer;
    }

    public string Length { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDriverEquipmentStraightTruckDomain : ApplicationDriverEquipmentAbstractDomain
{
    public ApplicationDriverEquipmentStraightTruckDomain()
    {
        Type = ApplicationDriverEquipmentTypeStaticStringsDomain.StraightTruck;
    }

    public string VINNumber { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDriverEquipmentCargoVanDomain : ApplicationDriverEquipmentAbstractDomain
{
    public ApplicationDriverEquipmentCargoVanDomain()
    {
        Type = ApplicationDriverEquipmentTypeStaticStringsDomain.CargoVan;
    }

    public string VINNumber { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }
}

public static class ApplicationDriverEquipmentTypeStaticStringsDomain
{
    public const string Tractor = "Tractor";
    public const string Trailer = "Trailer";
    public const string StraightTruck = "Straight Truck";
    public const string CargoVan = "Cargo Van";
}
```

I wrote the following Automapper rules to resolve it:

```
        CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Application.ApplicationDriverEquipmentTractorDomain, Infrastructure.Asset.ApplicationDriverEquipment>()
            .ForMember(c => c.Type.Name, p => p.UseValue<string>(Domain.StaticStrings.ApplicationDriverEquipmentTypeStaticStringsDomain.Tractor));
        CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Application.ApplicationDriverEquipmentTrailerDomain, Infrastructure.Asset.ApplicationDriverEquipment>()
            .ForMember(c => c.Type.Name, p => p.UseValue<string>(Domain.StaticStrings.ApplicationDriverEquipmentTypeStaticStringsDomain.Trailer));
        CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Application.ApplicationDriverEquipmentStraightTruckDomain, Infrastructure.Asset.ApplicationDriverEquipment>()
            .ForMember(c => c.Type.Name, p => p.UseValue<string>(Domain.StaticStrings.ApplicationDriverEquipmentTypeStaticStringsDomain.StraightTruck));
        CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Application.ApplicationDriverEquipmentCargoVanDomain, Infrastructure.Asset.ApplicationDriverEquipment>()
            .ForMember(c => c.Type.Name, p => p.UseValue<string>(Domain.StaticStrings.ApplicationDriverEquipmentTypeStaticStringsDomain.CargoVan));
```

I got an error:

> Expression 'c => c.Type.Name' must resolve to top-level member and not
>   any child object's properties. Use a custom resolver on the child type
>   or the AfterMap option instead.

**UPDATE**

I rewrote maps:

```
        CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Application.ApplicationDriverEquipmentTractorDomain, Infrastructure.Asset.ApplicationDriverEquipment>()
            .AfterMap((src, dest)=> dest.Type.Name = Domain.StaticStrings.ApplicationDriverEquipmentTypeStaticStringsDomain.Tractor);
        CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Application.ApplicationDriverEquipmentTrailerDomain, Infrastructure.Asset.ApplicationDriverEquipment>()
            .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Type.Name = Domain.StaticStrings.ApplicationDriverEquipmentTypeStaticStringsDomain.Trailer);
        CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Application.ApplicationDriverEquipmentStraightTruckDomain, Infrastructure.Asset.ApplicationDriverEquipment>()
            .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Type.Name = Domain.StaticStrings.ApplicationDriverEquipmentTypeStaticStringsDomain.StraightTruck);
        CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Application.ApplicationDriverEquipmentCargoVanDomain, Infrastructure.Asset.ApplicationDriverEquipment>()
            .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Type.Name = Domain.StaticStrings.ApplicationDriverEquipmentTypeStaticStringsDomain.CargoVan);
```

but now I got an error:

> Type Map configuration: ApplicationDriverEquipmentTractorDomain ->
>   ApplicationDriverEquipment
>   Domain.POCO.Application.ApplicationDriverEquipmentTractorDomain ->
>   Infrastructure.Asset.ApplicationDriverEquipment
>
> Property: Type ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing
>   type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types:
>
> String -> ApplicationDriverEquipmentType
>
> System.String -> Infrastructure.Asset.ApplicationDriverEquipmentType

Seems, I don't understand how to map it correctly

Comment: Type is a string in your class, does it have a name property?

Comment: @ironstone13, Type is a string for ApplicationDriverEquipmentAbstractDomain class, but has type ApplicationDriverEquipmentType for ApplicationDriverEquipment

Comment: Hey, @Oleh Sh, sorry for the wordy and iterative response, but I finally wrote it, please see my answer below. If you have any questions, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to map from
`ApplicationDriverEquipmentTractorDomain.Type` is a `string`
to
`ApplicationDriverEquipment.Type` is a `ApplicationDriverEquipmentType`

Where is your mapping configuration for that?

Is it even possible to map a string to a `ApplicationDriverEquipmentType`?
Sure, you can have a `string Name`, but where do you get the `Id` and `Equipments`?

I suspect you don't want to create a new instance of that type each time you map, but rather you need to look up an instance from some dictionary, sort of a [registry pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html)

To implement this idea, you simply need to

1. Load all of the `ApplicationDriverEquipmentType` from DB
2. Put them in a dictionary (assuming name is unique)
3. Register a [custom type converter](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters) or [custom value resolver](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers) as below

One way to implement this would be to use a [custom type converter](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters)
You could use something like
  `void ConvertUsing(Func<TSource, TDestination> mappingFunction);`
And put in your own function that would resolve your `ApplicationDriverEquipmentType` by name, **assuming name is unique** like this:

```
var applicationEquipments = new ApplicationDriverEquipmentTypeRepository().FindAll(); // get all the values somehow from db
var dictionary = applicationEquipments.ToDictionary(x=>x.Name);
Func<string, ApplicationDriverEquipmentType> resolver = x=>dictionary[x];
```

Yet another way to do this would be to use a [custom value resolver](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers)
Essentially, the idea would be the same - map of pre-loaded objects, only the way you "plug it in" would be different

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `MapFrom` method instead:

```
.ForMember(c => c.Type.Name, p => p.MapFrom(s => Domain.StaticStrings.ApplicationDriverEquipmentTypeStaticStringsDomain.Tractor));
```

Comment: @OlegSh why have you set the Type like this `c => c.Type.Name` in the Mapping logic. As far as I can see it is a simple string property so it must be `c => c.Type`

Comment: @raimondBurgaj, as you can see, Type has type ApplicationDriverEquipmentType , not string in destination class :)